# Can you create a consolidated PDF document using various other excel and worksheets Vbscript

Tags: excel, pdf, printing, vbscript, ms-word

I have 4 excel sheets and 1 word document,  with each excel having 5 tabs.

I want to create a consolidated PDF document of all these consolidated.

```
Sheet 1 - TabA  (Page 1)
Sheet 2 - TabB  (Page 1)
Sheet 3 - TabC  (Page 1 to Page 3)
Sheet 4 - Tab D and Tab E
WordDoc1 - Page 4 to Page 5
```

The place where I work, print all these documents physically, staple them together and file them. I want to change this process and save paper.

I am preferring VBscript over VBA because I think it'd be faster since these are huge files.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this once, or just a few times, this wiki can help you merge multiple files into one PDF file:
http://www.wikihow.com/Merge-PDF-Files

Merging can be done with a third party (web based services) and by the full Adobe suite (Click 'create' at the top left corner and then select 'combine files into a single PDF'). In Abode you can even select individual pages from the documents you want included and discard the ones you do not.

It sounds like the people in your company are manually clicking on each file to print anyways, so at least this method will save paper, and save *some* time. Hopefully someone has a suggestion that can be done in VBA

Answer (score 0):

How i would do this;
Create a temporary folder where you export each pdf by VBA eg: c:\temp\currenttime
Concatenate these different pdf's by using Sedja-console, initiated out of VBA with correct parameters